# Open WPD Device in Windows Explorer from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpd

I am currently working on an application for managing a WPD device.
I want to add an option to open the wpd device in windows explorer to view the saved files.
Problem is that I can't find a way to open explorer pointing to the device's "folder".
I have all information of the device (pnp device id, class name, etc.)
Anybody knows a solution?

Comment: What is "WPD"? (I assume you don't mean Word Perfect Document.)

Comment: WPD stands for "Windows Portable Devices" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Someone seems to have posted an answer similar to this:

[WPD equivalent of WIA DeviceDlg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464965/wpd-equivalent-of-wia-devicedlg/487330#487330)

also you could try enumerating all the children of the "My Computer" node - WPD devices usually show up there. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms909867.aspx

Start with the desktop and then enumerate the my computer node and then the children of that. Maybe there is a property that will enable you to pick the child of My Computer that corresponds to the WPD device.